# Vue.js настройка ssr

Tags: vue.js, seo, nuxt.js, ssr

Появилась необходимость подключения (настройки) ssr.
Никогда ранее не сталкивался с этим, vue.js изучаю буквально 3-4 месяца.
Для чего нужно: улучшить SEO.- на страницу с фильтрами, товары будут подтягиваться с бэка.

Вопрос, возможно ли это сделать на уже имеющемся проекте, без использования nuxt? С чего начать?
(Если нужны какие-то данные, спрашивайте, отвечу)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам в любом случае нужен какой-то инструмент, который поддерживает работу SSR и имеет для этого необходимый функционал. Из коробки Vue 2.x не готов к такому, поэтому популярностью пользуются как большие продукты (`Nuxt`, `Quasar`, `Vite` etc.), так и небольшие либы, которые будут брать ваш проект и запускать его на сервере при соблюдении некоторых правил разработки изоморфных приложений, иначе не запустится.

Отвечая на вопрос: без подключения дополнительных библиотек - нет, не получится. Но вам никто не мешает использовать Nuxt в уже запущенном проекте, но это может потребовать внести некоторые изменения в логику, если она не отвечает требованиям изоморфности. Также вы можете попробовать поискать что-то более легковесное типа `vue-server-renderer`.

P.S. - Возможно вам для улучшения покрытия SEO может быть достаточно пререндеринга?

Comment: Спасибо большое. Думаю, мне нужно больше протестировать на практике, дабы понять. могу ли я использовать пререндеринг на странице фильтров.